# Can JQUERY UI date picker show day name instead of a date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any way in jQuery UI Date Picker to show a day name (like "Tuesday") instead of a date?

I know that, by default, it only shows a date (like "09/09/2011"), but instead I want it to display "Friday".

Is there option for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `dateFormat` option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat.

In your case, I'd start with the constant: `DD` for the long form day name. Here is a full list of constants: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

**Example:**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exmaple:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD' });
```

Or see the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `DD`

`$.datepicker.formatDate('DD', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));`

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/):

> ### Options
>
> #### `dateFormat` - String Default: 'mm/dd/yy'
>
> The format for parsed and displayed dates. This attribute is one of
>   the regionalisation attributes. For a full list of the possible
>   formats see the `formatDate` function.

"`formatDate`" links to [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate), which conveniently lists "day of week (long form)" as `DD`.

So, pass `"DD"` as the `dateFormat` option to your Datepicker widget.

Note that this affects input parsing as well as display.